# Ruby sequel multiple operators

Tags: mysql, sql, sequel

How can i add multiple operators to apply this:

```rb
where deleted is not null and (status in ('PENDING', 'REMOVING') 
or (status='FAILED' and published_at is null))
```

with Ruby and Sequel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is:

```
.exclude(deleted: nil)
.where(
  Sequel.|(
    { status: %w[PENDING REMOVING] },
    { status: 'FAILED', published_at: nil }
  )
)
```